# JS Function is not defined but it is

Tags: javascript, html, razor-pages

Hey guys I have this js snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayDeliveryOptions() {
        var deliveryType = document.querySelector('input[name="deliveryType"]:checked').value;

        if (deliveryType === "homedelivery") {
            document.getElementById("pickupOptions").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("deliveryOptions").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("pickupOptions").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("deliveryOptions").style.display = "none";
        }
    } 
    function updateDeliveryPrice() {
        var selectedOption = document.querySelector('[name="deliveryTime"] option:checked');
        document.querySelector('#deliveryPrice').value = selectedOption.dataset.price;
        document.getElementById('priceLbl').innerHTML = selectedOption.dataset.price + '€';
        var total = @Model.Total + parseInt(selectedOption.dataset.price);
        totalLbl.textContent = total;
    }   

    
    function submitForm() {
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("deliveryForm"));
        fetch("/checkout", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
</script>
```

That applies to the following HTML:

```
<div><form id="deliveryForm" method="post">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="homedelivery" onchange="displayDeliveryOptions()"> Home Delivery
                </label>
                <br>
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="deliveryType" value="pickup" onchange="displayDeliveryOptions()"> Pickup
                </label>
                <br>
                <div id="pickupOptions" style="display:none">
                    <label for="pickupLocation">Pickup Location:</label><br>
                    <select name="pickupLocation">
                        @foreach (PickUp x in Model.PickUpList.DistinctBy(x => x.Location))
                        {
                            <option value="@x.Location">@x.Location</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label for="pickupDate">Pickup Date:</label><br>
                    <select name="pickupDate">
                        @foreach (PickUp x in Model.PickUpList.DistinctBy(x => x.Timeslot.Date))
                        {
                            if (x.DeliveryStatus == DeliveryStatus.AVAILABLE)
                            {
                                <option value="@x.Timeslot.Date">@x.Timeslot.Date.ToShortDateString()</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label for="pickupTime">Pickup Time:</label><br>
                    <select name="pickupTime">
                        @foreach (PickUp x in Model.PickUpList.DistinctBy(x => x.Timeslot.Time))
                        {
                            if (x.DeliveryStatus == DeliveryStatus.AVAILABLE)
                            {
                                <option value="@x.Timeslot.Time">@x.Timeslot.Time</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="deliveryOptions" style="display:none">
                    <label for="deliveryDate">Delivery Date:</label><br>
                    <select name="deliveryDate">
                        @foreach (HomeDelivery x in Model.DeliveryList.DistinctBy(x => x.Timeslot.Date))
                        {
                            if (x.DeliveryStatus == DeliveryStatus.AVAILABLE)
                            {
                                <option value="@x.Timeslot.Date">@x.Timeslot.Date.ToShortDateString()</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label for="deliveryTime">Delivery Time and Price:</label><br>
                    <select name="deliveryTime" onchange="updateDeliveryPrice()">
                        @foreach (HomeDelivery x in Model.DeliveryList.DistinctBy(x => x.Timeslot.Time))
                        {
                            if (x.DeliveryStatus == DeliveryStatus.AVAILABLE)
                            {
                                <option value="@x.Timeslot.Time" data-price="@x.Price">@x.Timeslot.Time - @x.Price</option>
                            }
                        }
                    </select>
                    <input type="hidden" name="deliveryPrice" id="deliveryPrice">

                </div>
            </form>                    <input class="btn btn-dark rounded-pill py-2 btn-block" type="button" value="Pay!" onclick="submitForm()" />

        </div>
```

I get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined  on displayDeliveryOptions but it doesn't make any sense because it is defined.

Any ideas? I've been stuck on it for hours and I'm in an absolute deadlock.

Thank you in advance

EDIT: So apparently the JS snippets work, displayDeliveryOptions and submitForm work but only if updateDeliveryPrice is removed from the code, what is going on here?

EDI2: Fixed by changing the updateDeliveryPrice to

```
 function updateDeliveryPrice() {
        const deliveryTimeOption = document.querySelector('select[name="deliveryTime"] option:checked');

        const deliveryPrice = deliveryTimeOption.getAttribute('data-price');

        document.getElementById('deliveryPrice').value = deliveryPrice;
    }
```

Comment: You’ll need to include the exact, complete error and when it occurs.

Comment: Hey, this is the error I see in my devtools:
Uncaught ReferenceError: displayDeliveryOptions is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onchange (Checkout:138:116)
onchange @ Checkout:138
It occurs when I click the radiobutton to choose the delivery type.
Is there supposed to be a longer error log?
thanks for your help

Comment: Make sure the script is defined after the html you showed, otherwise it can't find the functions.

Comment: I tried just now, script was inside body, moved it after html and before itand it doesn't work:( The JS code should be correct right?

Comment: script must be inside the body, as last content, otherwise use type="module"...

Comment: That's how it was at the beginning. I tried removing the updateDeliveryPrice code and for whatever reason it now works: what's the issue with updateDeliveryPrice? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing the updateDeliveryPrice to

```
 function updateDeliveryPrice() {
        const deliveryTimeOption = document.querySelector('select[name="deliveryTime"] option:checked');

        const deliveryPrice = deliveryTimeOption.getAttribute('data-price');

        document.getElementById('deliveryPrice').value = deliveryPrice;
    }
```

not sure where the error was but it works now! Yay!